# How does Pops survive?

Tags: plot-explanation, terminator-series, terminator-genisys

At the end of *Terminator: Genisys* we see Pops die after being flung out of the time displacement device:

[image: Pop dying]

How does he then show up again later in the movie?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's established early in the film that the poly-alloy can be used to repair the terminator. When the T1000 finds the "killed" young Arnie T800 you'll notice it drops some of itself into the head wound.  This brings the T800 back to functioning again to chase Kyle Reese.

So the remains of Pops landing in a tank of polyalloy was more than fortuitous.

Comment: Bingo! it was plainly foreshadowed.

Comment: I have one problem with the repair theory: the skin was not supposed to be repaired. Yet, Pops loses his battle scars and tissue damage. That's why it looks to me as if his CPU acquired a T-1000(ish) body.

Answer (score 5):

As T-800 himself explained:

> Polyalloy requires programming to take permanent form.
>   Without the CPU, it is harmless.

And T-800 does have a CPU, so this mishap acquired him a new body, similar (identical?) to the one that T-1000's have.

Answer (score 1):

You may recall that he explains this; he didn't die, he was 'upgraded'.  They never really specify what that means, but I believe it has to do with him being coated with the liquid metal.

Comment: Which explains how he was able to turn his arm into a blade to open that door.